# Python-Tornado on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, tornado

I am trying to deploy Tornado on Heroku. I am able to run a simple "hello world" app on using this method:
http://kzk9.net/deploying-tornado-on-heroku-mac-os-x

But while trying Tornado demo-app "chatdemo", the server is crashing with following logs:

```
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18442] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18442] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18442)
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18443] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18443] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18443)
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18444] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18444] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18444)
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18445] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 461, in spawn_worker
11:22:45 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 101, in init_process
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
11:22:45 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
11:22:45 web.1  |     app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  | NameError: name 'application' is not defined
11:22:45 web.1  | 2012-11-12 11:22:45 [18445] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18445)
11:22:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
11:22:45 web.1  |     load_entry_point('gunicorn==0.15.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 32, in run
11:22:45 web.1  |     WSGIApplication("%prog [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE").run()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 124, in run
11:22:45 web.1  |     Arbiter(self).run()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 185, in run
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 280, in halt
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.stop()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 328, in stop
11:22:45 web.1  |     self.reap_workers()
11:22:45 web.1  |   File "/Users/princekumar/Downloads/tornado-2.4/demos/ChatOnHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 421, in reap_workers
11:22:45 web.1  |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
11:22:45 web.1  | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
11:22:45 web.1  | exited with code 1
11:22:45 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Anybody has any idea whats wrong?

Comment: answering my own question: The only change needed is the configuration file and requirement file.

Comment: Kindly consider writing your answer in the answers place, and mark it as the chosen answer so we know you don't need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `procfile` and `requirements.txt`. If anyone is looking, [here](https://github.com/avinassh/talkwithme) is one working example of same official chat demo deployed on Heroku

Answer (score 1):

Your Procfile should contain the following :

```
 web: python app.py
```

(replace app.py with 'chatdemo.py' or the name of your app)

Answer (score 1):

Answers provided by @avi and @apoclyps arestill working fine on Tornado 6.1 as of July 2021.

My Procfile for Tornado web app appears below. It also works on AWS:

`web: python application.py --port=$port --logging=error`